# Deleting alpha numeric word from a string in php

Tags: php

We have been trying to remove a particular alpha numeric characters from a string in php. Example of the string is given below

```
1 .COIMBATORE (C) WARD NO 55  AMMANKULAM NORTH VAIKALMEDU
```

From the above cited string, like to remove  "WARD NO 55". We would like to have an output like this finally.

```
1 .COIMBATORE (C) AMMANKULAM NORTH VAIKALMEDU.
```

Comment: What is the logic behind this? Is there always 'WARD NO' followed by a number? So you always want to remove 'WARD NO', when it is followed by a number, and nothing else?

Comment: There is always WARD NO followed by a number. in every string. We would like to remove WARD NO with the number. The problem here is that that WARD NO word remains the same but number associated with it changes. That's why there is a problem in using preg_replace or str_replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case where regular expressions can be useful.

```
$text = '1 .COIMBATORE (C) WARD NO 55 AMMANKULAM NORTH VAIKALMEDU';
$text = preg_replace('/WARD NO ([0-9]+)/i','',$text);
$text = str_replace('  ',' ',$text); // remove double spaces
echo $text;
```

This returns:

```
1 .COIMBATORE (C) AMMANKULAM NORTH VAIKALMEDU
```

it is case insensitive and will replace multiple occurrences of 'WARD NO xx'.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

I always find it useful to test regular expressions here: https://regex101.com

You can also use that site to document your expression. Personally I dislike regular expression because they are difficult to read, so I avoid them when I can. However when it comes to matching strings nothing is better.

Comment: Hey thanks. Its working, but another problem, what if WARD NO 55 is at the end of a string.

Comment: Yes, I added the extra space after the number to prevent double spaces. You could put the space in front of WARD NO, but then you have the same problem when the WARD NO is at the front of the string. I would use a two step approach that will always work, I will edit my answer.